# I'm getting this error: Class "Zend_Validate_File_Upload" not found in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento 2.4.6 install and Im having a problem with this module: Bss grouped-product-with-custom-option Im getting this error

And There is an error in,

```
/chroot/home/abc/abc.abc.io/html/vendor/bsscommerce/grouped-product-with-custom-option/Model/Validate/File/Upload.php at line: 21 Class "Zend_Validate_File_Upload" not found
```

I've had a few other issues with zend files with this install. I was able to fix WeltPixel ga4 that uses a zend file but I cant find the equivalent for this file. Is there a replacement for this in the magento framework files or some other third party?

*update:  I changed the file to Laminas\Validator\File\Upload based of a github thread but now it immediately threw another error

```
/vendor/bsscommerce/grouped-product-with-custom-option/Model/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php at line: 21
Class "Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http" not found
```

so now im trying to find that equivalent,
so any suggestions would be great

Comment: This is third-party module `bsscommerce/grouped-product-with-custom-option`. You should contact module owner.

Answer (score 0):

- In Magento 2.4.6, the Zend Framework library has been removed, and as a result, the classes prefixed with "Zend_" are no longer available. Therefore, the class Zend_Validate_File_Upload is not found in Magento 2.4.6.
- To resolve this issue, you will need to update your code to use the appropriate classes or alternatives provided by Magento itself. Instead of relying on the Zend Framework classes, Magento provides its own set of classes for file validation.

You can use the Magento\Framework\File\Uploader class to handle file uploads and perform validations. Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'your_file_field_name']);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);

        try {
            $result = $uploader->save('your_destination_directory');
            // File upload successful, perform further actions
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // File upload error
        }

        // ...
        // Rest of your controller logic
        // ...
    }
}
```

- In the code above, make sure to replace 'your_file_field_name' with the actual name of your file input field and 'your_destination_directory' with the desired directory path where you want to save the uploaded files.
- By using the UploaderFactory class, you can handle file uploads and perform validations without relying on the deprecated Zend_Validate_File_Upload class.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Magento v2.4.6, and a few days ago, I encountered the same error, but I eventually resolved it.

The error indicates that you need to increase the value of the **[upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)** in the php.ini file. If you look up the Laminas\Validator\File\Upload class, you will find code that returns the following error message:

[magento root]/vendor/laminas/laminas-validator/src/File/Upload.php on 39 line.

```
self::INI_SIZE => "File '%value%' exceeds upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
```

[image]

In conclusion, it is suggesting that the issue is related to the PHP configuration in the php.ini file.